# Error while installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 using a bootable USB stick, but this error message is showing while I'm trying to install it.

[image: third partition table is not empty]

Comment: Running Disk Management in Windows will show you what's behind Door Number, err, Partition Three.

Answer (score 2):

Did you resize your windows partition?
Try logging into windows, using Disk Management shrink your windows partition than try installing Ubuntu after.

Hopefully that works for you